# Swift compiler error: Cannot invoke 'lockForConfiguration' with an argument list of type '(() -> ())'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

This is Swift 2. I can't seem to find anything on this. I am getting the error

```
Cannot invoke 'lockForConfiguration' with an argument list of type '(() -> ())'
```

On the second line here.

```
if let device = captureDevice {
            device.lockForConfiguration() {
                device.videoZoomFactor = 1.0 + CGFloat(ratioValue)
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        print(ratioValue)
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Swift 2 the method `lockForConfiguration` doesn't take any arguments but instead can throw an `NSError`. You should wrap it in a `do`-`try`-`catch` statement.

```
do {
    try device.lockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    // handle error
    return
}

// When this point is reached, we can be sure that the locking succeeded
device.videoZoomFactor = 1.0 + CGFloat(ratioValue)
device.unlockForConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
if let device = captureDevice {
    device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
    device.videoZoomFactor = 1.0 + CGFloat(ratioValue)
    device.unlockForConfiguration()
    print(ratioValue)
}
```

Comment: Getting 'Cannot invoke 'lockForConfiguration' with an argument list of type '(nil)'' and 'Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled' on the same line.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this line of code:

```
device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
```

Comment: I get 'Extra argument in call'

Comment: I tuoni you have to handle the error.Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/lockForConfiguration: